# Converting "Mar 13, 2013 05:30pm" to an NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-parsing

I have the following string `"Mar 13, 2013 05:30pm"` . I want to convert it into the `NSDate` object.

I have tried the following way but it is not working.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM:dd, YYYY hh:mm:aa"];
date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you get output?

Comment: Read this: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
NSString *stringDate = @"Mar 13, 2013 05:30pm";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mmaa"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"Date : %@",date);
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: "String" as a variable name? ;-)

Comment: yes.. its NSString *String

Comment: What significance is the leading uppercase char?  (Which you've now removed, which makes this thread of comments confusing, heh)

Comment: @JamesBoutcher Its not real coding competition here, dont care here about Camel casing ;)

Comment: Interestingly only yyyy worked, I tried YYYY also.

Comment: @ravijimagna Yes, yyyy should always be lower case..

Comment: I marked it as an accepted answer. Why would anyone downvote it. LOL :D

Comment: @P.J : Your code's output gives wrong time like: "Date : 2013-03-13 12:00:00 +0000", so "12:00:00" is not proper.

Comment: @sunilz Its write as you missed +0530 UTC... You should be aware about this..

Comment: @P.J : you are also write in this case as ravijimagna has not asked for exact output as they want, but now i can't give up vote as it was locked unless you have to edit this answer to allow me to up vote.

Comment: @sunilz Dunno if you are iOS developer or not, but every iOS developer are aware about UTC timings related to NSDateFormatter

Comment: @P.J : i will note this thing for future.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDateFormatter *dFormate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dFormate setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy hh:mma"];
[dFormate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString *dateStr = @"Mar 13, 2013 05:30pm";
NSDate *date = [dFormate dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"Date : %@", date);
```

Comment: This code is wrong, YYYY should be lower case yyyy. This results wrong answer.. :)

Comment: Hi your code will working if you change "hh:mm:a" to "hh:mma".

Comment: @P.J= why u jealous ??? please explain why it is wrong ??

Comment: @iPatel Try my code with YYYY instead of yyyy, it gives you wrong answer.

Comment: @P.J- okay i agree with u..but be positive, ur answer is accepted by OP. thats plus point bro :)